# Using tasks declared in interfaces within a package

Tags: interface, package, system-verilog, test-bench

I was trying to create a simple SV testbench and I ran into an issue when I couldnt not use a task declared in an interface within a package because an interface cannot be declared within a package. I have the following:

Defining my interface:

```
interface dut_tb_if ();

 task ahb_read();
 endtask

 task ahb_write();
 endtask

endinterface
```

Defining my testbench

```
module dut_tb();

 import dut_tb_pkg::*;

 dut_tb_intf dut_tb_intf();

 dut dut (.......);

endmodule
```

My testbench and test are the top-level modules so my test would look like this:

```
module dut_test1();

import dut_tb_pkg::*;

initial
begin
 dut_tb.dut_tb.intf.ahb_write(addr, wdata);
 dut_tb.dut_tb.intf.ahb_read(addr, rdata);
end
endmodule
```

I would like to declare new tasks in my package that uses the tasks from the interface and can stimulate this  within the testbench. How could I accomplish this within the package? Could someone please point me to an example.

Thanks
NV

Answer (score 0):

System verilog provides `virtual interfaces` which help solving those issues. This would require to pass a pointer to the interface to task in the package though. Here is an example:

```
package pkg;
 task u(virtual interface A a); // a task in package with a virtual interface in argumetns
  $display("%m in pkg");
  a.t();  // call the task from the interface.
 endtask
endpackage  

interface A;
  task t;
    $display("%m: task in A");
  endtask
endinterface


module top;
  A a();  // instantiate interface
  initial begin
    pkg::u(a); // call the package task and pass the interface pointer to it.
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks this is elegant way to resolve this - will try it out